How to create AppleInternalVariant.plist (for debugging purpose)
How to create AppleInternal variant on macOS?
It seems that AppleInternal folder is only working for Simulator to get debug menus etc.
One has to create file under /System/Library/CoreServices/AppleInternalVariant.plist. I know for recent macOS installations this is a sealed Volume (cannot change). Is there any trick how to create this file?
#if !TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
#define INTERNAL_CONTENT_PATH "/System/Library/CoreServices/AppleInternalVariant.plist"
#else
#define INTERNAL_CONTENT_PATH "/AppleInternal"
#endif

Link to source code defining AppleInternal
The content of the file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppleInternal</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Link to AppleInternal plist file
PS: Creating AppleInternal folder under Data Volume does nothing (during recovery).

https://gist.github.com/macshome/15f995a4e849acd75caf14f2e50e7e98

It's actually possible to modify sealed volume.
Make sure to fully csrutil disable + csrutil authenticated-root disable
Create mounting folder mkdir /tmp/mount
Mount sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk3s1 /tmp/mount
Go to CoreServices cd /tmp/mount/System/Library/CoreServices
Create file named AppleInternalVariant.plist sudo touch AppleInternalVariant.plist
Edit file using nano sudo nano AppleInternalVariant.plist
Add following content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppleInternal</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Save
Create snapshot sudo bless --mount /tmp/mount --bootefi --create-snapshot
Restart.
After restart you can have debug menu in screencapture (hold ctrl+option+shift)


Thanks! I am also curious about your thinking process while discovering this
